# Android: Create new instance of bundle and pass to intent in dagger in mvp

Tags: dagger-2, android-mvp

I would like to use MVP with dagger in my project. 
In view I have this method and into this method I will pass some object to the presenter:

```
@Override
public void onLogin(User user, Cookie cookie, UUID sessionId, List<Permission> permissions) {
    super.onLogin(user, cookie, sessionId, permissions);
    presenter.onLogin(user, cookie, sessionId, permissions);
}
```

Here is my presenter:

```
public class Presenter implements ILogin.LoginPresenter{

    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public Presenter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin(User user, Cookie cookie, UUID sessionId, List<Permission> permissions) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);///?
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();///?
        bundle.putString("USER", user.getUserName());
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I have nothing in module :

```
@Module
public class LoginModule {
}
```

My questions:

1. Is it true that I am creating new object (`Intent` and `Bundle`) in the presenter when I am using dagger?
2. How could I use dagger to my scenario? That's mean create new instance of intent and bundle in module class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of MVP pattern is to separate business logic from its view. It's a common good practice not to have any android framework related code in your presenter (here your presenter depends on `Context`, `Intent` and `Bundle` from the android framework).

In your case, you should not create your `Intent` and `Bundle` in your presenter since it belongs to your view (`MainActivity`).

Your `onLogin` function could look like this:

```
@Override
public void onLogin(User user, Cookie cookie, UUID sessionId, List<Permission> permissions) {
    // whatever is your business logic
    view.showMainActivity(user);
}
```

where `view` is an interface implemented by your `MainActivity` and injected in your presenter.

Comment: I think it is not good idea store those information in to preferences . I think preferences job is something else and it is not secure. I think is better to use eventBus or something else!!Dude what is your idea? @Benjamin